# Can I read webview's cookies in an Electron app?

Tags: cookies, electron

When using a WebView element for displaying other pages inside an Electron app, is it possible to read and write its cookies?

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can:

### Access cookies via session:

```js
const { session } = require('electron').remote

// Here we access the session via the partition name
// You could also get it from the webContents object
// (webContents.session)
const cookies = session.fromPartition(<yourWebviewPartionName>).cookies

// Get a specific Cookie
cookies.get(
  {
    url: <targetURL>,
    name: <cookieName>
  }, 
  (error, result) => console.log('Found the following cookies', result)
)

// Get all cookies
cookies.get(
  {}, 
  (error, result) => console.log('Found the following cookies', result)
)

// Remove a cookie
cookies.remove(
  <targetURL>,
  <cookieName>,
  error => {
    if (error) throw error
    console.log('cookie deleted')
  }
)
```

### Other ways of accessig cookies in electron:

- since cookies are part of the http protocol you could rewrite the cookie headers via electrons [webrequest](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/session/#seswebrequest) api
- you could access `document.cookies` via contentscripts ([preload](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#preload) scripts)

### More Info:

- [webview](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/)
- [webContents](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/)
- [session](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/session/)

Comment: I can't edit this response, But there is no `{}` in the `.remove` of cookies. it takes three different params. `url,name,cb`

Comment: Can I also access http only session cookies this way? Does not seem to work for me :/