# How to handle access tokens and refresh tokens in Express app

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I have a desktop application running on localhost:3000 and a express app running on localhost:6001. Currently I implemented the PKCE flow to grab access tokens from the auth server.

**Process**

`Front-End(http://localhost:3000)`

Sends a get request to express app to generate an authorization uri link.

`Express App(http://localhost:6001)`

Creates code challenge, state and verifier variables. Sends back generated authorization uri link to the front end which then creates a electron window. The authorization redirect links back to an express app endpoint.

`Oauth Authorization Server`

After user authorizes app, authorization code is sent back to the express app  endpoint.

`Express App(http://localhost:6001/redirect)`

This endpoint reads the request from auth server which includes the auth code and then makes a post request to `oauth/token` endpoint to receive access token and refresh token.

My question is how can I manage the user session? Should I send the tokens to the front end or keep them in the express app?

Answer (score 0):

The usual flow for a desktop app is to follow [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252) and implement its own OpenID Connect flow, rather than to use a backend. So the login response should be returned to http://localhost:3000 in your example.

This involves user logins via the system browser, and the app listening for the response on either a local loopback HTTP address or using a private URI scheme. The desktop app can look after its own tokens, and store them in OS specific secure storage if needed.

Here are a couple of Electron apps of mine that you can run, to see what this looks like:

- [Initial Desktop Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample1)
- [Final Desktop Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final)

Comment: Interesting solution. There is a massive switching cost for me to start using this solution. P.S I wanna have a inline login-page type of solution. Any idea how to deal with the current setup that I have?

Comment: Is it okay if I store the JWT in locals?

Comment: The problem you seem to have is that there is probably no secure way to return the access token from the back end to the desktop app, so that it can call APIs. Any getAccessToken endpoint you provide to the desktop app could also be called by a malicious party. That is why the desktop app itself should receive tokens.

Comment: How about I store the AccessToken in something like a express-session and then define an endpoint that can handle the api calls for the frontend.. if that makes sense

Comment: ''like express-session stores only a session identifier on the client within a cookie and stores the session data on the server, typically in a database.''

Comment: You might be able to get [something based on cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651924/can-i-read-webviews-cookies-in-an-electron-app) to work, since Electron views are based on the Chromium browser. That is more of a browser based app approach, whereas my code samples use the [AppAuth-JS approach](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS).

Comment: Wow that's a great resource! I'm able to read the cookies in my main process; Now I'm thinking I should be storing a refresh token instead of an access token so that whenever the user opens back the application I can grab the refresh token and use to get the access token and user data. Is it okay if I store it locally using electron-store ?

Comment: Tokens should use [secure storage](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/tokenStorage.ts) rather than general storage